How can I generate a list of unique values by comparing values in different cells?
I guess my questions framing was too complicated :)
But here the issue I am trying to figure out.
Let's say I have two columns. "City" and "Number".
When working in this spreadsheet I will manually enter Cities and corresponding numbers in each row. There could be multiple rows for a city with different or same numbers.
=============================
Name         |   Number      
=============================
Denver       |   10
-----------------------------
San Diego    |   30
-----------------------------
Denver       |   10
-----------------------------
Denver       |   30

Now after entering, I want to have either a button on the page or run a macro that will generate a list where I want to generate one row for each unique City/Number pair. eg. the above list would generate a new set of columns whichever cell I run it on:
=============================
Name         |   Number      
=============================
Denver       |   10
-----------------------------
San Diego    |   30
-----------------------------
Denver       |   30

Just not sure how do I go about solving this?
Any tips appreciated.
Edit:
Things I have tried:
=UNIQUE($H5:$H14,TRUE, FALSE)

Using this I am able to create a douplicate of a column and show only unique entries. But Not sure how I can extend this to now compate the value with other column and also display City Name and Number for that match.

This question is not related with Excel Formula because you are requesting for a button or a macro. If you are asking to do it automatically without creating another range of data then you definitely need to use VBA here, BTW have you looked at using UNIQUE() function or using Power Query. One more thing because of the context of your post someone has downvoted. Per SO, when you are asking for help, you need to show what you have tried on your own, that way it will help users to help you more easily

Please share the code you've got so we can build on it. Surely you must be aware that you will have to loop through the rows.

Also why not use the Remove Duplicate feature found in Data Tab, it wont need a macro also. and here is a link I just researched over the SO Remove Dupes Using VBA and AnotherOne check some these links it might help you, and then if you cant post the code so that someone or as mentioned above by @VBasic2008 Sir can help you out!

I like this idea. Remove duplicate does exactly what I want. Only thing is, I have to manually copy the content and then run this. Which is OK and will do the job but I was still thinking if I could have a formula that I can use to do the same?

Added the code I have already tried.

The formula which you are using it already does =UNIQUE($H5:$H14,TRUE, FALSE) but it will create a new range of cells so you have to copy and paste it as values and then remove the old data. to all these you can record a simple macro. or you can follow the answer which is already posted by @VBasic2008 Sir.

For the sample data in my answer, you could use the following formula: =UNIQUE(A2:B11).

Copy and Remove Duplicates
Features





The Method
Sub CopyRemoveDupes()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy and Remove Duplicates"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "No range selected!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = Selection.Cells(1)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dcell.Worksheet
    
    If sws Is dws Then
        If Not Intersect(dcell, srg) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The destination cell """ & dcell.Address(0, 0) _
                & """ cannot be located in the source range """ _
                & srg.Address(0, 0) & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    srg.Copy dcell
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
    Dim ColsArray() As Variant: ReDim ColsArray(0 To cCount - 1)
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To cCount
        ColsArray(c - 1) = c
    Next c
    
    If rCount > 1 Then
        drg.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(ColsArray()), Header:=xlYes
    End If
    
    Dim drgNew As Range, drCount As Long, rowsRemoved As Long
    
    Set dcell = drg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If dcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data found in range """ & dws.Name & "!" _
            & drg.Address(0, 0) & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    Else
        drCount = dcell.Row - drg.Row + 1
        rowsRemoved = rCount - drCount
        Set drgNew = drg.Resize(drCount)
    End If
    
    MsgBox "The source range " & vbLf & vbTab _
        & sws.Name & "!" & srg.Address(0, 0) & vbLf _
        & "was copied to the destination range" & vbLf & vbTab _
        & dws.Name & "!" & drg.Address(0, 0) & "." & vbLf & "After removing " _
        & rowsRemoved & " row" & IIf(rowsRemoved = 1, "", "s") _
        & " of duplicates, the new destination range is" _
        & vbLf & vbTab & dws.Name & "!" & drgNew.Address(0, 0) & ".", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

